# Web browser for local application

Tags: windows, web-browser

I have a web application installed in a local web server.

I need to install a browser to the client computer.
I can use a common browser (firefox, chrome, ...) but I would like to know if something specific and customized exists for this purpose. For example I would like to avoid plugins, antivirus add-ons, bookmark and toolbars... I need only a browser as a terminal for local web app.

Moreover, I'm searching a customizable webbrowser not because it has to connect to local instead of remote site, but because I would like to use that web app as a local application with a custom icon in the desktop, a custom window title, without addressbar, toolbars and plugins like a standard webbrowser. I want to give to user perception of using an application and not to surf on a webpage.

Does something like this exist for the Windows platform?

Comment: OK, I've integrated that with your post. Are you willing to spend some money on it, or must it come free of charge?

Answer (score 1):

As *Chenmunka* said, try [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/) as it has good performance and it is very lightweight. I did exactly what you are trying to do using it, with good results, in a Raspberry PI.

Run Midori in Kiosk mode by doing `midori -e Fullscreen -a http://site-location-here`.

You can also try other browsers, just add "Kioski mode" to your searches, which is the term for that you are trying to do. There are Kioski Mode extensions for Firefox and Chrome as well you like them more.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it. Fullscreen/Kiosk mode is not required, but I would like to change icon/title of the browser process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have taken the trouble to create a web application, then you can also use a free Visual Studio Express edition and create the app yourself in C# or VB. All you need to do is create a Windows Forms application project, drop a web browser control on a form, set it address to the web application and build. It is very easy.

Comment: This can be a good idea, but is this html5 full compliant? I have SVG controls in my pages and I know that MS is not very standard-friendly. Can I found some web browser control for VB like webkit?

Comment: Mozilla or Chrome can be used but it will not be as easy as dropping the IE control.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/) browser.

This is lightweight, open-source and customizable.  Available free to use on Windows and Linux.

Midori does support bookmarks and plugins if you do wish to use them.  However, by tweaking Midori's configuration you can disable and/or hide everything.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you coding in? You can embed Chromium (Chrome rendering engine) in local apps using several languages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

If you are using PHP, there are some other choices -

PHP-GTK - http://gtk.php.net/download.php

PHP Desktop - https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop